# Is this thick-stemmed dark leafed plant a weed or a flower?

Tags: identification

I spotted this plant but I never knew its name and I wonder if it flowers. I tried to search it up but it shows that it is Amaranth but I don't think it looks like one. The leaves are dark green and the underside is green.

Note: I did not plant this plant.

The pictures are below:

[image: Side view of plant]
[image: Top view of plant]

Comment: You're right that it's not Amaranth, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plant looks like American burnweed (aka pilewort), a plant in the daisy family.

Comment: Hi B--rian  can you more details on how you identified this plant?

Comment: I hate common names, because that looks nothing like the "burnweed" in my area of the US :)

Answer (score 2):

weeds *are* flowers that you happen to dislike. Others call them a more romantic "locally native plants". Unless it spits out pollen or wildly creeps, you don't have to remove "weeds" if you like the look, and many are quite colorful at times.

That said, it's costing you a bit of money to have it live there by lowering the cooling ability of your AC by reducing airflow, so I would chop it ASAP.

Comment: Just wanting to know what type of weed.